# Can't create the directory <Some Directory> while is creating an Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I've been trying create an Azure Active Directory B2C Tenant 1, according the follow article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started

But some seconds after that of having clicked on the button create, it is shown a notification with a similar message at the these:

> Can't create the directory Foo. Error details: Can't be completed due a services connection error. Try again later

It is worth mentioning that this message is a translation into English of the original message, the original message says:

> No se pudo crear el directorio Foo. Detalles del error: No se puede completar debido a un error de conesión de servicios. Vuelva a intentarlo más tarde.

I hope someone can help me with this error. Beforehand thank you very much.

[Image with the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gft5V.jpg)

Comment: Curious, if you remove / from N/A does it still fail?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for reporting this issue. We apologize for the inconvenience and are taking necessary steps to prevent future reoccurrence. There was no impact on existing B2C directories management and authentication scenarios. This issue has been resolved now.